# Access memory with absolute address but not register value in GDB when debugging core dump

Tags: c++, gdb, coredump

I'm debugging a core dump file and having an issue about accessing memory addresses. But when i check the core dump, i arrived very confused.The address seems valid, but when i check $eax, it shows can't access, but whe i check the address with absolute address, it shows can access.

The program crashed when access $eax and the value of $eax is 0xdddfce30
When I try to examine a memory address stored in EAX by doing:

(gdb) x $eax

It gives an error saying the address is not accessible.

```
(gdb) x $eax
0xdddfce30:     Cannot access memory at address 0xdddfce30
```

However, if I use the concrete address directly like:

(gdb) x 0xdddfce30

GDB can read the memory contents.

```
(gdb) x 0xdddfce30
0xdddfce30:     0x00000000
```

So GDB is able to access the memory location with the absolute address, but not using the EAX register value extracted from the core dump.

When i use `maintenance info sections` to check the memory status. It shows the address can read and write.

```
    `/data/home/w4/work_bin/MyGame/MyGame_d', file type elf32-i386.
    0x8048134->0x8048147 at 0x00000134: .interp ALLOC LOAD READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
    0x8048148->0x8048168 at 0x00000148: .note.ABI-tag ALLOC LOAD READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
    0x8048168->0x804818c at 0x00000168: .note.gnu.build-id ALLOC LOAD READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
    0x804818c->0x804d178 at 0x0000018c: .gnu.hash ALLOC LOAD READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
    0x804d178->0x8057ae8 at 0x00005178: .dynsym ALLOC LOAD READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
    0x8057ae8->0x807df4c at 0x0000fae8: .dynstr ALLOC LOAD READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
    0x807df4c->0x807f47a at 0x00035f4c: .gnu.version ALLOC LOAD READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
    0x807f47c->0x807f5bc at 0x0003747c: .gnu.version_r ALLOC LOAD READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
    0x807f5bc->0x807f5ec at 0x000375bc: .rel.dyn ALLOC LOAD READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
    0x807f5ec->0x807fb24 at 0x000375ec: .rel.plt ALLOC LOAD READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
    0x807fb24->0x807fb54 at 0x00037b24: .init ALLOC LOAD READONLY CODE HAS_CONTENTS
    0x807fb54->0x80805d4 at 0x00037b54: .plt ALLOC LOAD READONLY CODE HAS_CONTENTS
    0x80805e0->0x80b445c at 0x000385e0: .text ALLOC LOAD READONLY CODE HAS_CONTENTS
    0x80b445c->0x80b4478 at 0x0006c45c: .fini ALLOC LOAD READONLY CODE HAS_CONTENTS
    0x80b4480->0x80c1188 at 0x0006c480: .rodata ALLOC LOAD READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
    0x80c1188->0x80c529c at 0x00079188: .eh_frame_hdr ALLOC LOAD READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
    0x80c529c->0x80d6498 at 0x0007d29c: .eh_frame ALLOC LOAD READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
    0x80d6498->0x80d6fcd at 0x0008e498: .gcc_except_table ALLOC LOAD READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
    0x80d7000->0x80d7024 at 0x0008f000: .ctors ALLOC LOAD DATA HAS_CONTENTS
    0x80d7024->0x80d702c at 0x0008f024: .dtors ALLOC LOAD DATA HAS_CONTENTS
    0x80d702c->0x80d7030 at 0x0008f02c: .jcr ALLOC LOAD DATA HAS_CONTENTS
    0x80d7030->0x80d7128 at 0x0008f030: .dynamic ALLOC LOAD DATA HAS_CONTENTS
    0x80d7128->0x80d712c at 0x0008f128: .got ALLOC LOAD DATA HAS_CONTENTS
    0x80d712c->0x80d73d4 at 0x0008f12c: .got.plt ALLOC LOAD DATA HAS_CONTENTS
    0x80d73e0->0x80d8180 at 0x0008f3e0: .data ALLOC LOAD DATA HAS_CONTENTS
    0x80d8180->0x80dea44 at 0x00090180: .bss ALLOC
    0x0000->0x002d at 0x00090180: .comment READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x3768 at 0x000901ad: .debug_aranges READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x3b187 at 0x00093915: .debug_pubnames READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0xe0aab at 0x000cea9c: .debug_info READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0xcbb7 at 0x001af547: .debug_abbrev READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x14c93 at 0x001bc0fe: .debug_line READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x585f2 at 0x001d0d91: .debug_str READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x8801 at 0x00229383: .debug_pubtypes READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x3680 at 0x00231b84: .debug_ranges READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
Core file:
    `/data/home/w4/work_bin/MyGame/core_MyGame_d_1689827015.1377', file type elf32-i386.
    0x0000->0xa1ac at 0x00000e74: note0 READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0044 at 0x00000ed0: .reg/1384 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0044 at 0x00000ed0: .reg HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x00a0 at 0x00001050: .auxv HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x006c at 0x00001628: .reg2/1384 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x006c at 0x00001628: .reg2 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0200 at 0x000016a8: .reg-xfp/1384 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0200 at 0x000016a8: .reg-xfp HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0a80 at 0x000018bc: .reg-xstate/1384 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0a80 at 0x000018bc: .reg-xstate HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0044 at 0x000023dc: .reg/1385 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x006c at 0x00002438: .reg2/1385 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0200 at 0x000024b8: .reg-xfp/1385 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0a80 at 0x000026cc: .reg-xstate/1385 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0044 at 0x000031ec: .reg/1388 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x006c at 0x00003248: .reg2/1388 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0200 at 0x000032c8: .reg-xfp/1388 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0a80 at 0x000034dc: .reg-xstate/1388 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0044 at 0x00003ffc: .reg/1386 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x006c at 0x00004058: .reg2/1386 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0200 at 0x000040d8: .reg-xfp/1386 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0a80 at 0x000042ec: .reg-xstate/1386 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0044 at 0x00004e0c: .reg/1390 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x006c at 0x00004e68: .reg2/1390 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0200 at 0x00004ee8: .reg-xfp/1390 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0a80 at 0x000050fc: .reg-xstate/1390 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0044 at 0x00005c1c: .reg/1387 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x006c at 0x00005c78: .reg2/1387 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0200 at 0x00005cf8: .reg-xfp/1387 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0a80 at 0x00005f0c: .reg-xstate/1387 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0044 at 0x00006a2c: .reg/1389 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x006c at 0x00006a88: .reg2/1389 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0200 at 0x00006b08: .reg-xfp/1389 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0a80 at 0x00006d1c: .reg-xstate/1389 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0044 at 0x0000783c: .reg/1377 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x006c at 0x00007898: .reg2/1377 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0200 at 0x00007918: .reg-xfp/1377 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0a80 at 0x00007b2c: .reg-xstate/1377 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0044 at 0x0000864c: .reg/1383 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x006c at 0x000086a8: .reg2/1383 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0200 at 0x00008728: .reg-xfp/1383 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0a80 at 0x0000893c: .reg-xstate/1383 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0044 at 0x0000945c: .reg/1381 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x006c at 0x000094b8: .reg2/1381 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0200 at 0x00009538: .reg-xfp/1381 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0a80 at 0x0000974c: .reg-xstate/1381 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0044 at 0x0000a26c: .reg/1382 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x006c at 0x0000a2c8: .reg2/1382 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0200 at 0x0000a348: .reg-xfp/1382 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x0000->0x0a80 at 0x0000a55c: .reg-xstate/1382 HAS_CONTENTS
    0x8048000->0x8049000 at 0x0000c000: load1a ALLOC LOAD READONLY CODE HAS_CONTENTS
    0x8049000->0x8049000 at 0x0000d000: load1b ALLOC READONLY CODE
    0x80d7000->0x80d9000 at 0x0000d000: load2 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0x80d9000->0x80df000 at 0x0000f000: load3 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0x9c7a000->0x9c9b000 at 0x00015000: load4 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0x9c9b000->0x9eee000 at 0x00036000: load5 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xc42d2000->0xc43d5000 at 0x00289000: load6 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xc4900000->0xc4935000 at 0x0038c000: load7 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xc4935000->0xc4935000 at 0x003c1000: load8 ALLOC READONLY
    0xc4b00000->0xc4b22000 at 0x003c1000: load9 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xc4b22000->0xc4b22000 at 0x003e3000: load10 ALLOC READONLY
    0xc4d00000->0xc4d30000 at 0x003e3000: load11 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xc4d30000->0xc4d30000 at 0x00413000: load12 ALLOC READONLY
    0xc4e00000->0xc4f00000 at 0x00413000: load13 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xc5000000->0xc509b000 at 0x00513000: load14 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xc509b000->0xc509b000 at 0x005ae000: load15 ALLOC READONLY
    0xc51dc000->0xd6aed000 at 0x005ae000: load16 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xd6cee000->0xd6ef4000 at 0x11ebf000: load17 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xd6ff2000->0xd70f5000 at 0x120c5000: load18 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xd7100000->0xd7200000 at 0x121c8000: load19 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xd7300000->0xd7400000 at 0x122c8000: load20 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xd7400000->0xd7500000 at 0x123c8000: load21 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xd7500000->0xd7600000 at 0x124c8000: load22 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xd7600000->0xd7700000 at 0x125c8000: load23 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xd7800000->0xd7900000 at 0x126c8000: load24 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xd7900000->0xd7a00000 at 0x127c8000: load25 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xd7b00000->0xd7c00000 at 0x128c8000: load26 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xd7c00000->0xd7d00000 at 0x129c8000: load27 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xd7d00000->0xd7e00000 at 0x12ac8000: load28 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xd7e00000->0xd7f00000 at 0x12bc8000: load29 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xd7f00000->0xd8000000 at 0x12cc8000: load30 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xd80fd000->0xdab00000 at 0x12dc8000: load31 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xdab00000->0xdac00000 at 0x157cb000: load32 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xdad00000->0xdadfe000 at 0x158cb000: load33 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xdadfe000->0xdadfe000 at 0x159c9000: load34 ALLOC READONLY
    0xdae00000->0xdaeff000 at 0x159c9000: load35 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xdaeff000->0xdaeff000 at 0x15ac8000: load36 ALLOC READONLY
    0xdaf00000->0xdb000000 at 0x15ac8000: load37 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xdb0fe000->0xdd900000 at 0x15bc8000: load38 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xdd900000->0xdda00000 at 0x183ca000: load39 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xdda00000->0xddaf6000 at 0x184ca000: load40 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xddaf6000->0xddaf6000 at 0x185c0000: load41 ALLOC READONLY
    0xddb00000->0xddbfd000 at 0x185c0000: load42 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xddbfd000->0xddbfd000 at 0x186bd000: load43 ALLOC READONLY
    0xddc00000->0xddcf8000 at 0x186bd000: load44 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xddcf8000->0xddcf8000 at 0x187b5000: load45 ALLOC READONLY
    0xddd00000->0xdddfd000 at 0x187b5000: load46 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xdddfd000->0xdddfd000 at 0x188b2000: load47 ALLOC READONLY
    0xdde98000->0xe389d000 at 0x188b2000: load48 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe389d000->0xe389e000 at 0x1e2b7000: load49 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe389e000->0xe54ec000 at 0x1e2b8000: load50 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe54ec000->0xe54ed000 at 0x1ff06000: load51 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe54ed000->0xe713b000 at 0x1ff07000: load52 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe713b000->0xe713c000 at 0x21b55000: load53 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe713c000->0xe8d8a000 at 0x21b56000: load54 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe8d8a000->0xe8d8b000 at 0x237a4000: load55 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xe8d8b000->0xea9d9000 at 0x237a5000: load56 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xea9d9000->0xea9da000 at 0x253f3000: load57 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xea9da000->0xec628000 at 0x253f4000: load58 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xec628000->0xec629000 at 0x27042000: load59 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xec629000->0xee277000 at 0x27043000: load60 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xee277000->0xee278000 at 0x28c91000: load61 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xee278000->0xefec6000 at 0x28c92000: load62 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xefec6000->0xefec7000 at 0x2a8e0000: load63 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xefec7000->0xf1b15000 at 0x2a8e1000: load64 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf1b15000->0xf1b16000 at 0x2c52f000: load65 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf1b16000->0xf5567000 at 0x2c530000: load66 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf5567000->0xf5567000 at 0x2ff81000: load67 ALLOC READONLY
    0xf5600000->0xf56f8000 at 0x2ff81000: load68 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf56f8000->0xf56f8000 at 0x30079000: load69 ALLOC READONLY
    0xf5709000->0xf5755000 at 0x30079000: load70 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf5755000->0xf5755000 at 0x300c5000: load71 ALLOC READONLY
    0xf578a000->0xf578b000 at 0x300c5000: load72 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf578b000->0xf5f8b000 at 0x300c6000: load73 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf5f8b000->0xf5f8c000 at 0x308c6000: load74a ALLOC LOAD READONLY CODE HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf5f8c000->0xf5f8c000 at 0x308c7000: load74b ALLOC READONLY CODE
    0xf5fa5000->0xf5fa6000 at 0x308c7000: load75 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf5fa6000->0xf5fa7000 at 0x308c8000: load76 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf5fa7000->0xf678a000 at 0x308c9000: load77 ALLOC LOAD READONLY CODE HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf678a000->0xf680f000 at 0x310ac000: load78 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf680f000->0xf7441000 at 0x31131000: load79 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf7441000->0xf7444000 at 0x31d63000: load80 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf7444000->0xf7445000 at 0x31d66000: load81a ALLOC LOAD READONLY CODE HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf7445000->0xf7445000 at 0x31d67000: load81b ALLOC READONLY CODE
    0xf75d4000->0xf75d6000 at 0x31d67000: load82 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf75d6000->0xf75d7000 at 0x31d69000: load83 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf75d7000->0xf75da000 at 0x31d6a000: load84 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf75da000->0xf75db000 at 0x31d6d000: load85a ALLOC LOAD READONLY CODE HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf75db000->0xf75db000 at 0x31d6e000: load85b ALLOC READONLY CODE
    0xf75f7000->0xf75f8000 at 0x31d6e000: load86 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf75f8000->0xf75f9000 at 0x31d6f000: load87a ALLOC LOAD READONLY CODE HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf75f9000->0xf75f9000 at 0x31d70000: load87b ALLOC READONLY CODE
    0xf7620000->0xf7621000 at 0x31d70000: load88 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf7621000->0xf7622000 at 0x31d71000: load89 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf7622000->0xf7623000 at 0x31d72000: load90a ALLOC LOAD READONLY CODE HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf7623000->0xf7623000 at 0x31d73000: load90b ALLOC READONLY CODE
    0xf7701000->0xf7705000 at 0x31d73000: load91 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf7705000->0xf7706000 at 0x31d77000: load92 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf7706000->0xf770d000 at 0x31d78000: load93 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf770d000->0xf770e000 at 0x31d7f000: load94a ALLOC LOAD READONLY CODE HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf770e000->0xf770e000 at 0x31d80000: load94b ALLOC READONLY CODE
    0xf7714000->0xf7715000 at 0x31d80000: load95 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf7715000->0xf7716000 at 0x31d81000: load96 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf7716000->0xf7717000 at 0x31d82000: load97a ALLOC LOAD READONLY CODE HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf7717000->0xf7717000 at 0x31d83000: load97b ALLOC READONLY CODE
    0xf772d000->0xf772e000 at 0x31d83000: load98 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf772e000->0xf772f000 at 0x31d84000: load99 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf772f000->0xf7731000 at 0x31d85000: load100 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf7731000->0xf7732000 at 0x31d87000: load101a ALLOC LOAD READONLY CODE HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf7732000->0xf7732000 at 0x31d88000: load101b ALLOC READONLY CODE
    0xf7734000->0xf7735000 at 0x31d88000: load102 ALLOC LOAD READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
    0xf7735000->0xf7736000 at 0x31d89000: load103 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
```

Why does the program while crash at this address? Why does it give an access error when using the register value and can access with absolute address?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Please let me know if any other details would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> So GDB is able to access the memory location with the absolute address, but not using the EAX register value extracted from the core dump.

This just means that there is a bug in GDB -- there should be *absolutely* no difference between the two `x` commands.

The segment in the `core` you are trying to access:

```
    0xddd00000->0xdddfd000 at 0x187b5000: load46 ALLOC LOAD HAS_CONTENTS
```

is `0xfd000` in size, which is a pretty standard Linux/ix86 stack size.

One reason it could be inaccessible is that the `core` was truncated. Is the core larger than `0x188b2000` (411,770,880 bytes) ? If it's not, that would explain the missing data (but not why the program crashed).

Comment: The size of the core is 798M.

Comment: @SheepBluesky I suggest updating GDB to the latest version -- the bug may have been fixed since. Other than that, I am out of ideas :-(